# Can Atom feed contain media:content tag?

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I have atom feed from some source in my app. It is sending me media:content tag for image information. I did not find anywhere this tag is supported  Atom feed as per standards. This is for rss only.

Please let me know if atom feed can have media:content tag as per standards or not.

Thanks

Comment: The question is why would you need these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An atom feed can include a `content` element in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace.

The namespace *can* be assigned to the `media:` prefix, although it is usually assigned to the `atom:` prefix.

So it is *possible* that the document is standards compliant and pure Atom, but impossible to tell without knowing what namespace `media:` represents in your example.

It is also possible for [other XML types to be included](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-6.1).